# Achievements dialog doesn't show tag badge progress

Tags: bug, tag-badges, achievements-dialog

The new addition to the achievement dialog shows your current progress to a privilege or and a badge. If you are a trusted user (20K) it shows the progress to your next tag badge.

However: the progress doesn't show any progress, while the profile page does (although separate from the actual badge icon). The current UI doesn't add anything if it doesn't include the progress! What do I need to do to get that badge?

> [image: Broken]

Can this be fixed or even removed if it isn't possible to include any useful information regarding the progress?

Comment: Patrick is this same [A/B testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev) thing? If yes, look at the progress bar shared of images in the post

Comment: @HackerKarma it is. But the first shows privilege progress, which can be shown. The tag badge progress is different. It doesn't show anything useful now.

Comment: No, the tag badge [tag:design]. It shows empty. @HackerKarma

Comment: Ahha ... got it. So when you click it 'shows empty' That's definitely a Bug. +1.

Comment: @Pat tag badge shows no progress in profile page as well so guess it's by design

Comment: @Sha that is what I said indeed, it shows next to it in the profile. So please incorporate that or leave it out. It is meaningless now.

Comment: Sorry for being thick (probably) but you say "while the profile page does" - but it doesn't... so what am I missing here? I agree it doesn't look good but still not convinced it's a bug.

Comment: @Sha Not sure how to tag it otherwise. The vital information in the profile page isn't the badge icon, it is the numbers next to it, and that vital information is not in the view. So the 'bug' lies in the missing information, but
 a technical issue.

Comment: @Sha do your think it should be a feature request?

Comment: Feels more like a feature request, yes - but sad fact is, that bugs get attention faster so maybe better leave it as bug, and worst case a dev will retag at some point.