# Change 'next badge' in the new Achievements Dialog

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, achievements-dialog

I'm most active in the Physics SE. As you might now, there we [still](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) have the *old* profile page, so we don't have the 'next badge' progress bar.
Or at least, we didn't have the progress bar until last week. Now it's visible at the bottom of the [new Achievements Dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev). Good, but... there is no way to change the target badge!

In the sites with the *new* profile page (I've tried in WorldBuilding SE), you can click the gear icon next to the progress bar and change to your favourite badge. Then, the badge in the Achievemnts Dialog changes accordingly. But in Physics SE, no new profile page means no gear button. :(

Can this be changed in order to make the bahaviour of the old-profile-sites more consistent? I don't know what would the best option (a 'gear icon' in dialog/removing the badge progress bar/other ideas), but in the current form, it's basically useless.

Comment: I think this is just an issue of the A/B testing going on which doesn't make a distinction between users that are able to set it or not. I guess every community has to get the new design, but that might take some time...

Comment: This is an oversight on our end. Now, we're still A/B testing this change (i.e. we may decide not to keep it), so this may stay as-is for a little bit. However, if we decide to roll the feature out, we'll make sure we fix this. Thanks for the report!

Comment: So can this be considered a functional bug? @ThomasOrozco